# Acronis Managed Machine Service Mini все время грузит систему, как узнать что она делает?

Tags: windows-8, windows-service

- Windows 8.1
- Acronis True Image 2018

При установке системы и необходимых для работы программ, все работало стабильно несколько месяцев.
В последнее время стал замечать тормоза и вижу что

"Acronis Managed Machine Service Mini" все время грузит процессор на 30% при этом показатели памяти не меняются равно как и нет операций чтения/записи с диском.

Как понять что она делает или не делает а тупо жрет ресурсы?
Автоматические бекапы диска отключены, делаю бекапы исключительно в ручном режиме.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю запустить утилиту [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx)

Далее нужно выбрать фильтрацию , например, по имени процесса, и включить фильтр. Вот так вы сможете смотреть чем занимается процесс, в какие файлы, ветки реестра она пишет. Попробуйте отключить службу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]